# Views : Make a block related to a page (with flag/addthis/privatemsg as fields in this block)

Tags: 7, views, flags, privatemsg

It's difficult to explain but i'll try to do my best.

I have a basic views (Page) with all my fields displaying.
My purpose is to take some of this fields to display them in a block(on the left sidebar)

**This fields i want to display in a block are:**

- Flag: bookmarks
- AddThis: Toolbox
- Private msg (send message to the author)

I follow all the screemcast "Taming the beast" (from nodeone.se) especially part 24 when Johan Falk explain how to make a block with a related content to a page (without using page manager)

When i go to my article my url is like that: **/fiches-produits-services/100**  (100=>[nid])

I follow this step when i create my block:

- Add my fields etc.
- Add contextual filter : **content: nid**
- click on it, go to **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE**
- Click on **Provide default value**
- Select **Content ID from url**

But after that nothing, the block isn't here.
When i click on **Display all results for the specified field** on the same section, the block appears but with all the flags, the privatemsg and socials icons from all my article.

It's not the bahavior i want, i would like to have just the flag related to the article, just the link from private messages related to the article etc.

I don't know if i missed something. In the screemcast he did that with content(article) related with another content (basic page), maybe we can't do that with flag, addThis or privatemsg because it's not really a content (But i don't really know i'm new).

So if someone can help me to understand that, i'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way this week to get the good behavior.

i understood my mistake! My url was like that *www.example.com/my-product/2* (made with pathauto)

When i selected **content ID from URL** my block was empty because he couldn't retrieve the good argument from the url (because my node id was in second position)
But when i go to *www.example.com/node/2* it works fine

To resolve my problem i select **raw value from URL**  instead of **content ID from URL** (because with that option we can select which argument we want to retrieve --that was the second for me because of my custom url)

In summary i follow this step :

- Add contextual filter : content: nid
- click on it, go to WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE
- Click on Provide default value
- Select **raw value from URL**
- Select the argument you want to retrieve from the url (path component)
- I check **Specify validation criteria**
- **Validator** : content
- **Filter value format** : node id
- **Action to take if filter value does not validate** : no result

It was a stupid mistake :) but i learn some stuff :)